# Relationsip in Core Data with 3 entitys with circle sheme

Tags: sqlite, core-data, entity, relationship

My application store gifts for contacts and events. It has 3 entity – Contacts, Events and Gifts. Contacts has many-to-many relationship with Events, and Events has one-to-many Relationsip with Gifts. The model is:
Conacts –many-to-many – Events – one- to-many – Gifts
When one contact has many events and every event has one or many gifts all is OK.
But when  one Event (as Christmas) has many members (contacts), it seem’s we need additional relationship between Contacts and Gifts. But when I try create this relationship, Xcode crash. Because it is a circle? I know, it is very simple, when you work with SQL table directly. You create additional table, that discribe relationship between all table. But how can I make it in Core Data? My be how know it?

Answer (score 0):

You create an additional entity which describes the relationship between Gifts, Persons and Events.
In my example I call this entity Giver:

[image]

For Contacts who don't bring gifts (or for an earlier stage, where you don't know what they bring) I would create an additional Many-to-Many relationship between Contact and Event:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it's all rigth in my application.